# MacOS Panic every time it goes to sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

My MacBook Pro throws a kernel panic after some time in sleep... it doesn't happen always, but very often.

I have MacOS Monterey (12.0.1) installed.

Here's the panic report

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff024212024): macOS panic detected
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 19P549
macOS version: 21A559
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0: Wed Oct 13 18:09:06 PDT 2021; root:xnu-8019.41.5~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 5206FA9B-BD6D-381D-A198-5F6E6A09B67F
iBoot version: iBoot-7429.41.4
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0x16
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x5
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x40001000100
PCIeUp link state: not available
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:      0x000000001c184000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff023188000
mach_absolute_time: 0x1da76bab913
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x62b78ff2 0x00081f0a
  Sleep   : 0x62ba522c 0x000ee80a
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x62ba522d 0x0000f63f

Zone info:
Foreign   : 0xfffffff08e1b4000 - 0xfffffff08e1c4000
Native    : 0xffffffe000218000 - 0xffffffe600218000
Readonly  : 0 - 0
Metadata  : 0xffffffeb00828000 - 0xffffffeb04a60000
Bitmaps   : 0xffffffeb02028000 - 0xffffffeb022ac000
CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 1: PC=0x0000000000000000, LR=0x0000000000000000, FP=0x0000000000000000
Panicked task 0xffffffe0f2ac8658: 0 pages, 231 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe0f32ea490, backtrace: 0xffffffeb0ed03670, tid: 397
          lr: 0xfffffff02396f388  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed036b0
          lr: 0xfffffff02396f118  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed03720
          lr: 0xfffffff023aa7eac  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed037a0
          lr: 0xfffffff023aa703c  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed03850
          lr: 0xfffffff023fd15fc  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed03860
          lr: 0xfffffff02396ee2c  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed03bf0
          lr: 0xfffffff02396ee2c  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed03c50
          lr: 0xfffffff024ac3488  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed03c70
          lr: 0xfffffff024212024  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed03ca0
          lr: 0xfffffff0241fef5c  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed03d00
          lr: 0xfffffff024205410  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed03d50
          lr: 0xfffffff024200e48  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed03df0
          lr: 0xfffffff0241fe640  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed03e70
          lr: 0xfffffff0240b0db4  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed03ea0
          lr: 0xfffffff023f173a4  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed03ee0
          lr: 0xfffffff023f16bb4  fp: 0xffffffeb0ed03f20
          lr: 0xfffffff023fdc5a0  fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

UPDATE: A new panic happened to me even I updated to the latest OS version

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff015420ef8): macOS panic detected
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 19P5071
macOS version: 21F79
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0: Tue Apr 26 20:35:13 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.121.3~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 015E49E0-D2AC-3BFD-9465-D0AAA435B13E
iBoot version: iBoot-7459.121.2
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0x16
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x5
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x10001000100
PCIeUp link state: not available
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:      0x000000000d36c000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff014370000
mach_absolute_time: 0xdab8e5003e
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x62be4ba9 0x000b622a
  Sleep   : 0x62c19569 0x000c7fbe
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x62c19569 0x000dd343

Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffffe027ce0000 - 0xffffffe627ce0000
  . VM    : 0xffffffe027ce0000 - 0xffffffe10e344000
  . RO    : 0xffffffe10e344000 - 0xffffffe15b010000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffffe15b010000 - 0xffffffe241674000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffffe241674000 - 0xffffffe327cd8000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffffe327cd8000 - 0xffffffe40e340000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffffe40e340000 - 0xffffffe4f49a8000
  . DATA  : 0xffffffe4f49a8000 - 0xffffffe627ce0000
  Metadata: 0xffffffe0061f4000 - 0xffffffe0079f4000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffe0079f4000 - 0xffffffe007c50000

CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 1: PC=0x0000000000000000, LR=0x0000000000000000, FP=0x0000000000000000
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Panicked task 0xffffffe40e2e8628: 0 pages, 229 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe40e850df0, backtrace: 0xffffffe633e23670, tid: 403
          lr: 0xfffffff014b7e504  fp: 0xffffffe633e236b0
          lr: 0xfffffff014b7e28c  fp: 0xffffffe633e23720
          lr: 0xfffffff014cb6a40  fp: 0xffffffe633e23790
          lr: 0xfffffff014cb5aa4  fp: 0xffffffe633e23840
          lr: 0xfffffff0151d95fc  fp: 0xffffffe633e23850
          lr: 0xfffffff014b7dfa8  fp: 0xffffffe633e23be0
          lr: 0xfffffff014b7dfa8  fp: 0xffffffe633e23c40
          lr: 0xfffffff015cff340  fp: 0xffffffe633e23c60
          lr: 0xfffffff015420ef8  fp: 0xffffffe633e23c90
          lr: 0xfffffff01540dd08  fp: 0xffffffe633e23cf0
          lr: 0xfffffff015414118  fp: 0xffffffe633e23d40
          lr: 0xfffffff01540fb6c  fp: 0xffffffe633e23de0
          lr: 0xfffffff01540d3c4  fp: 0xffffffe633e23e60
          lr: 0xfffffff0152bbde8  fp: 0xffffffe633e23e90
          lr: 0xfffffff015122528  fp: 0xffffffe633e23ee0
          lr: 0xfffffff015121e04  fp: 0xffffffe633e23f20
          lr: 0xfffffff0151e45a0  fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

UPDATE 2: I ran the Apple Diagnostics and nothing was wrong. Results attached below

[image: Apple Diagnostics results]

Comment: 12.0.1 is quite old. Many bugs have been fixed since. Please update to 12.4 and see if this still occurs.

Comment: I updated... will update the post if the panic happens again

Comment: @pion I updated to the latest version (12.4) and I got another panic just now... I updated the question with the report of the new panic

Comment: Have you run [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)? What was the result?

Comment: No, didn't run it... will do it in the weekend and will update the post with the results

Comment: hi @DavidSupportsMonica I just uploaded the Apple Diagnostics results... it seems that all went fine

Comment: That result (no hardware issues found) suggests it's a software problem. Thus: create a new user, and spend a little time in that user account; if no kernel panics occur, there's something in your regular user account that's triggering the issue. If kernel panics continue, the issue isn't a user account defect, and the treatment would be to reload macOS using Recovery.

Comment: I've had similar issues on a 2015 MBP with i7. Turns out the entire motherboard needed to be replaced for about $500 through Apple Genius Bar. I didn't opt for that, but instead got a new machine with M1 which doesn't crash. It's probably a faulty motherboard, something you could replace yourself if you bought the right parts. What is the computer model, specs, year?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I think I'm just going to format the mac entirely... get back to factory settings and check from there

Comment: @PeterNielsen I have a 16-inch 2019 2,3 GHz Intel Core i9

Comment: I think that's a reasonable course of action. If the computer misbehaves with a new user (and any old user **not** logged in) in a new macOS, the fault must be hardware-related, and was not discovered by Apple Diagnostics.

Comment: @AugustoHerbel I formatted my computer and it kernel panicked on the first five minutes of booting up with a new OS. It's definitely hardware.